# Sass operator to include parent's class in the child's rule

Tags: sass

Current code:

```
.parent-1 {
    .child {
        @include set-position-offset(10px, 20px);
    }
}
.parent-2 {
    .child {
        @include set-position-offset(20px, 30px);
    }
}
.parent-3 {
    .child {
        @include set-position-offset(30px, 40px);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the above code?

Like the following style:

```
.child {
    {some operator}.parent-1 {
        @include set-position-offset(10px, 20px);
    }
    {some operator}.parent-2 {
        @include set-position-offset(20px, 30px);
    }
    {some operator}.parent-3 {
        @include set-position-offset(30px, 40px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trailing ampersand - `selector & { ... }` - should do the trick:

```
.child {
    .parent-1 & {
        @include set-position-offset(10px, 20px);
    }
    .parent-2 & {
        @include set-position-offset(20px, 30px);
    }
    .parent-3 & {
        @include set-position-offset(30px, 40px);
    }
}
```

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand

Answer (score 0):

you can use looping, like this :

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .parent-#{$i} {
    .child {
      @include set-position-offset(10px * $i, (10px * $i) + 10);
    }
  }
}
```